# How can I add pagination to search result

Tags: php, search, pagination

I am trying add search result to pagination. I'm lost - I've tried almost all combinations. This is my unresolved problem - if search result is "wlo" - there are 2 pages (count 11 result), but whe I click Next or 2 - all the results are showing.
[http://Test site](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/produkty/public/staff/pages/index.php)

**Code index.php**

```
<?php

$search_statement = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$search = db_escape($db, $search_statement);

$sql1  = "SELECT * "; 
$sql1 .= "FROM products ";
$sql1 .= "WHERE (`prod_name` LIKE '%".$search."%') ";

$products_sql_count = mysqli_query($db, $sql1);
$products_count = mysqli_num_rows($products_sql_count);
mysqli_free_result($products_sql_count);

$rowperpage = 10;

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '1';

$page = $page - 1;

$p = $page * $rowperpage;

$search_statement = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$search = db_escape($db, $search_statement);

$sql  = "SELECT * "; 
$sql .= "FROM products ";
$sql .= "WHERE (`prod_name` LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY cat_id ASC, position ASC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT ".$p.", ".$rowperpage." ";  

$products_set = mysqli_query ($db, $sql);
echo $sql;
```

**Links**

```
<?php 
    echo '<br />';

    $page_nb = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '1';

    $check = $p + $rowperpage;

    if($products_count > $check) {
      $next_page = $page_nb + 1;
      echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$next_page."&".$search."'>Next</a> ";
    }

    $limit = $products_count / $rowperpage;
    $limit = ceil($limit);

    for($i = max(1, $page_nb - 5); $i <= min($page_nb + 5, $limit); $i++){

        echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."&".$search."'>".$i." </a> " ;

        }

    if($page_nb > 1) {
      $prev_page = $page_nb - 1;
      echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$prev_page."&".$search."'>Back</a>";
    }

    echo '<br /><br />';

    ?>
```

Comment: Your first query should be a `SELECT COUNT(col)` Why build a resultset you are not going to use

Comment: _if search result is "wlo"_ ? Dont know what that means

Comment: I using this to insert '  $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $products['cat_id']) . "',";'

Comment: where is "open to SQL Injection Attack"? I use everywhere this function 'db_escape($connection, $string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  }'

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your search string in query string as well. Change code as below:

```
echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$prev_page."&search=".$search."'>Back</a>";
```

Please make changes in all lines according to above. Also, you need to make changes in your PHP code for seacrh string as below code:

```
$search_statement = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
if ($search_statement == '') {
    $search_statement = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';        
}
```

And I think you should only apply where search string content when there is any search string as below:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * "; 
$sql .= "FROM products ";
if ($search != '') {
    $sql .= "WHERE (`prod_name` LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
    $search = db_escape($db, $search_statement);
}
$sql .= "ORDER BY cat_id ASC, position ASC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT ".$p.", ".$rowperpage." ";
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It should not be - $search_statement = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';  ?

Comment: Works - Thank you very much - problem was 2 x "GET" - I did not know:)

Comment: I have one more question for you. Is this code secure? I use everywhere this function 'function db_escape($connection, $string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  }'

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is using `POST` you should use `GET`, ie change `$_POST` to `$_GET` and also change the `method="post"` to `method="get"` in your `<form>` HTML tag, or alternatively, remove the method attribute as GET is the default.

Your second issue is the way you append the search parameter in your link, you are currently doing `&{$search}` whereas you should be doing `&search={$search}`

Or to keep it in the same format as you had it `"&search=" . $search . "`.

Please keep in mind this code is bad practice, and very likely susceptible to SQL Injection please look into the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) API for PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I using something like that '$sql = "INSERT INTO products ";
    $sql .= "(cat_id, prod_name, filename, type, size, position, visible, content) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $products['cat_id']) . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $products['prod_name']) . "',";'

Comment: I am assuming this is in response to my PDO comment, in which case no that isn't similar to PDO usages. Here is the first tutorial i found, which seems to be fairly decent: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Yes - I meant  I using this function to SQL Injection 'function db_escape($connection, $string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  }'

Comment: I know that PDO is better